# Convert to uk timezone from US timezone

Tags: php, time, timezone

I'm interested in finding out how I can send the UK time to my server at UTC_TIMESTAMP updates the server at server time and being on a shared server they won't allow a server time change and I have to do it by php
Or can I convert it when I echo the date out from the database with a function? I don't know what the best possible solution is.

Here is my query

```
$insertmessage = "INSERT INTO messages(message_type_id,message_creator,message_target,message_content,message_throughurl,message_time,message_status) VALUES ($typeids,$creatorids,$targetusers,'$contents','$url',UTC_TIMESTAMP,'1')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the following line of code will only change your time for MySQL

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'dbuser', 'dbpassword');
$db->exec("SET time_zone='GMT'");
```

If you want to also change the timezone of PHP try the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: It will work with MySQLi as long as you run this query before inserting your new rows. "SET timezone = 'GMT'"

Comment: Could I add the above SET into my insert query at all so the code is all neatly in one insert? And you're being very helpful, thank you.

Comment: YEs you can put it in your query in one insert, even thought it might not be the optimal way. No problem Dave, hopefully your problem will be solved!

Comment: Any chance this would work?
`$timestamp = strtotime('UTC_TIMESTAMP') + 60*60;
    $time = date('H:i', $timestamp);`

And then use $time as the value to insert into the database?

Comment: If your Timezone is UTC you can just use `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` at the top of your PHP script and your Timezone for PHP will already be set. You can then convert your time like so: `$date = date(H:i', time());`